# Best approach to make android device a remote for C game

Tags: android, c, sockets, sdl

I have a game write in C/SDL (a kind of space invaders), and I want develop an android app to control the game like my keyboard.
So my question is : What is the best way to success that ?

- Directly make a communication between the android App and the C program with socket or something like that  ?
- Have a small programme who make the link between the android app and the C program ?

-Something else ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend either a socket connection, or if your computer has a Bluetooth receiver a Bluetooth connection. Bluetooth is more energy-efficient, and provides the necessary low-latency. There is an application on the market called "Bluetooth Remote PC" as proof of concept.

Comment: I think a socket connection will be better cause "Bluetooth Remote PC" don't let me the choice to design an UI no ? cause I want on my android screen a sort of gamepad. So I can comunicate directly between my android and c program with socket ?

Comment: I didn't say use that application per say. I just meant: look! that app does something similar! you can write your own app that communicates with C using bluetooth.